# move semantics and cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, computer-vision, move-semantics

Opencv's [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) on `cv::Mat` seems to indicate that there are no move constructors at the moment, so something like `cv::Mat A=std::move(some_other_cv_mat)` doesn't make much sense. My current (and naïve) solution to this problem is to derive a class from `cv::Mat`, for which I implement a move constructor as follows:

```
namespace cv
{
    //matrix object derived from cv::Mat
    class Mvbl_Mat final: public Mat 
    {
        public:
          //constructors
          Mvbl_Mat(){};
          Mvbl_Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, const Scalar   &s):Mat(rows, cols, type, s){}
         //destructor
         ~Mvbl_Mat(){};

          //move constructor
          Mvbl_Mat(Mvbl_Mat && other) noexcept
          {   
              this->data=other.data;
              other.data=nullptr;
           } 
          //move assignment operator
          Mvbl_Mat & operator=(Mvbl_Mat && other)
          {   
              this->data=other.data;
              other.data=nullptr;
              return *this; 
          }   
     };

}
```

While this works for the limited problems that I face at the moment, there are obviously many limitations and the solution is far from ideal. So, what is the best way to emulate move semantics for `cv::Mat`?

Comment: Why do you specialize if you provide move constructor/assignment?

Comment: Also, `move` does not make much sense for `cv::Mat` because the copy constructor does not copy the data. And your move constructor probably breaks the reference counter.

Comment: @Holt You are right, there is no need to specialize it, it makes no sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Holt I disagree. `move` makes a lot of sense, even, or especially for a refcount model (see `shared_ptr`). Imagine you'd like to pass a `Mat` into a function but you don't need the `Mat` for yourself after the call. Without `move` you are forced to hold on to your reference (and the memory) until the function returns. With `move` you have the opportunity to reuse memory within the function in such cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need to do this.  `cv::Mat`'s copy constructor doesn't actually copy the data.  It basically makes a reference and all objects share the same data.

[cv::Mat::Mat(const Mat & m)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a294eaf8a95d2f9c7be19ff594d06278e)

> This is an overloaded member function, provided for convenience. It differs from the above function only in what argument(s) it accepts.
>
> Parameters
>
> `m`    Array that (as a whole or partly) is assigned to the constructed matrix. No data is copied by these constructors. Instead, the header pointing to m data or its sub-array is constructed and associated with it. The reference counter, if any, is incremented. So, when you modify the matrix formed using such a constructor, you also modify the corresponding elements of m . If you want to have an independent copy of the sub-array, use Mat::clone()

Comment: Yes, but I want to be able to destroy the older object after that. With the copy constructor, I will lose the data if I delete the older object,  no?

Comment: @Ash What do you mean by "destroy"? `cv::Mat` has a reference count, so the data will only get destroyed when no `cv::Mat` owns it.

Comment: @Ash You shouldn't since it is reference counted.  It would just decrees the reference count.  It works like `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @NathanOliver A good refcount model like `shared_ptr` DOES support `move` semantics. Without `move` you can't pass your last reference into a function, you are forced to hold on to it (and the memory) unnecessarily until the function returns.

Comment: @Ash you mean move Mat content and detach from source?
Maybe this is what you're looking for

    `cv::Mat source = /*initialization*/ ;`
    `cv::Mat dest;`
    `cv::swap(source, dest);`

Answer (score 6):

As of 4.x OpenCV provides [`Mat (Mat &&m)`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adcaeb226bafeff8a1b262f57f6ffbcc4) and [`Mat & operator= (Mat &&m)`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a86d190d68dbd801a2bd555d0905979fd).

If you are working on a version prior to 4.x, I'd suggest to take a look at the `cv::Mat` move constructor and move assignment operator implementations defined in [`modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.0.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp), as it's a little more complicated that just copying the `.data` member.

Comment: Even in OpenCV 4.9.0, [`Mat(Mat&&)` is noexcept(false)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.9.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L2121), so it gets the vector pessimization and `folly::fbvector<cv::Mat>` doesn't compile at all ([folly#1821](https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/1821)). Any idea why the move constructor can't be `noexcept`? (And/or, to the people reading this in the future: When willen-have-been `noexcept` added to the move constructor?)